# What is the difference between CreateDymanic methods of SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic and TechTalk.SpecFlow.Assist?

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow

I am new to specflow. I was trying context injection for which I am using CreateDynamicSet on Table instance. I got to know that 'SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic' nuget is needed for this but when I used it, it remained unused and CreateDynamicSet was part of 'TechTalk.SpecFlow.Assist'.

Am I missing something or using something wrong here ? (Although I was able to use data between different step definitions as expected)

Or it seems 'TechTalk.SpecFlow.Assist' is the namespace for Dynamic methods then what is the use of 'SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic' package in context injection.

Comment: Which version of SpecFlow are you using?

Comment: Its SpecFlow 3, more specifically package version - 3.3.0.0 with VS 2017.